# Receptive field calculation for Google Net

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand the receptive field for GoogleNet.

I used the program as shown below.

```
import math
convnet =   [[7,2,3],[1,1,0],[3,2,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[3,2,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[3,2,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[5,3,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[5,3,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[3,2,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,0],[3,1,1],[1,1,0],[7,1,1]]
layer_names = ["conv1/7x7_s2","conv1/relu_7x7","pool1/3x3_s2","pool1/norm1","conv2/3x3_reduce","conv2/relu_3x3_reduce","conv2/3x3","conv2/relu_3x3","pool2/3x3_s2","inception_3a/3x3_reduce","inception_3a/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_3a/3x3","inception_3a/relu_3x3","inception_3b/3x3_reduce","inception_3b/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_3b/3x3","inception_3b/relu_3x3","pool3/3x3_s2","inception_4a/3x3_reduce","inception_4a/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_4a/3x3","inception_4a/relu_3x3","loss1/ave_pool","inception_4b/3x3_reduce","inception_4b/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_4b/3x3","inception_4b/relu_3x3","inception_4c/3x3_reduce","inception_4c/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_4c/3x3","inception_4c/relu_3x3","inception_4d/3x3_reduce","inception_4d/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_4d/3x3","inception_4d/relu_3x3","loss2/ave_pool","inception_4e/3x3_reduce","inception_4e/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_4e/3x3","inception_4e/relu_3x3","pool4/3x3_s2","inception_5a/3x3_reduce","inception_5a/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_5a/3x3","inception_5a/relu_3x3","inception_5b/3x3_reduce","inception_5b/relu_3x3_reduce","inception_5b/3x3","inception_5b/relu_3x3","pool5/7x7_s1"]
imsize = 720
def outFromIn(isz, layernum, net = convnet):
    if layernum>len(net): layernum=len(net)

    totstride = 1
    insize = isz
    #for layerparams in net:
    for layer in range(layernum):
        fsize, stride, pad = net[layer]
        outsize = (insize - fsize + 2*pad) / stride + 1
        insize = outsize
        totstride = totstride * stride
    return outsize, totstride

def inFromOut( layernum, net = convnet):
    if layernum>len(net): layernum=len(net)
    outsize = 1
    #for layerparams in net:
    for layer in reversed(range(layernum)):
        fsize, stride, pad = net[layer]
        outsize = ((outsize -1)* stride) + fsize
    RFsize = outsize
    return RFsize

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "layer output sizes given image = %dx%d" % (imsize, imsize)
    for i in range(len(convnet)):
        p = outFromIn(imsize,i+1)
        rf = inFromOut(i+1)
        print "Layer Name = %s, Output size = %3d, Stride = % 3d, RF size = %3d" % (layer_names[i], p[0], p[1], rf)
```

The receptive field for each layers are calculated as

```
layer output sizes given image = 224x224
Layer Name = conv1/7x7_s2, Output size = 112, Stride =   2, RF size =   7
Layer Name = conv1/relu_7x7, Output size = 112, Stride =   2, RF size =   7
Layer Name = pool1/3x3_s2, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  11
Layer Name = pool1/norm1, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  11
Layer Name = conv2/3x3_reduce, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  11
Layer Name = conv2/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  11
Layer Name = conv2/3x3, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  19
Layer Name = conv2/relu_3x3, Output size =  55, Stride =   4, RF size =  19
Layer Name = pool2/3x3_s2, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  27
Layer Name = inception_3a/3x3_reduce, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  27
Layer Name = inception_3a/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  27
Layer Name = inception_3a/3x3, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  43
Layer Name = inception_3a/relu_3x3, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  43
Layer Name = inception_3b/3x3_reduce, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  43
Layer Name = inception_3b/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  43
Layer Name = inception_3b/3x3, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  59
Layer Name = inception_3b/relu_3x3, Output size =  27, Stride =   8, RF size =  59
Layer Name = pool3/3x3_s2, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size =  75
Layer Name = inception_4a/3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size =  75
Layer Name = inception_4a/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size =  75
Layer Name = inception_4a/3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 107
Layer Name = inception_4a/relu_3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 107
Layer Name = inception_4b/3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 107
Layer Name = inception_4b/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 107
Layer Name = inception_4b/3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 139
Layer Name = inception_4b/relu_3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 139
Layer Name = inception_4c/3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 139
Layer Name = inception_4c/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 139
Layer Name = inception_4c/3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 171
Layer Name = inception_4c/relu_3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 171
Layer Name = inception_4d/3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 171
Layer Name = inception_4d/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 171
Layer Name = inception_4d/3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 203
Layer Name = inception_4d/relu_3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 203
Layer Name = inception_4e/3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 203
Layer Name = inception_4e/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 203
Layer Name = inception_4e/3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 235
Layer Name = inception_4e/relu_3x3, Output size =  13, Stride =  16, RF size = 235
Layer Name = pool4/3x3_s2, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 267
Layer Name = inception_5a/3x3_reduce, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 267
Layer Name = inception_5a/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 267
Layer Name = inception_5a/3x3, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 331
Layer Name = inception_5a/relu_3x3, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 331
Layer Name = inception_5b/3x3_reduce, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 331
Layer Name = inception_5b/relu_3x3_reduce, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 331
Layer Name = inception_5b/3x3, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 395
Layer Name = inception_5b/relu_3x3, Output size =   7, Stride =  32, RF size = 395
Layer Name = pool5/7x7_s1, Output size =   3, Stride =  32, RF size = 587
```

What I don't understand is that for the input image size of 224, the last layer should have receptive field size of approximately 224.

Now is 587 for pool5/7x7_s1 layer.

Inception module inception_4e has receptive field  that is approximately the same size as the input image size 224.

What is wrong with my calculation?
In the paper, it is clearly stated as the receptive field is 224 x 224 in the RGB color space with zero mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receptive field has nothing to do with input size:
The size of the receptive field tells you what "pixels" affect (or participate) in computing a single output of the net.
Note that when computing receptive field you completely ignore padding(!).

On the other hand, when you want to compute net's output size, you take into account both kernel sizes and strides (that affect receptive field) but **also** input size and padding.

Therefore, receptive field size and input/output sizes are related but by no means the same.

A nice guide to [receptive field arithmetics](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807).